# React axios storing token in local storage

Tags: reactjs, axios, token, storage, response

I have the following response coming back from a React Axios post request...

```
{
    "Id": 1,
    "UserName": "***",
    "Password": null,
    "Email": "***",
    "FirstName": "Steven",
    "Surname": "Collins",
    "CompanyName": "***",
    "OrisecAccountNumber": "***",
    "Token": "eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1bmlxdWVfbmFtZSI6InN0ZXZlLmNvbGxpbnNAb3Jpc2VjLmNvLnVrIiwicm9sZSI6WyJPcmlzZWNBZG1pbiIsIkluc3RhbGxlckFkbWluIl0sIm5iZiI6MTU3MzA2OTg2NiwiZXhwIjoxNTczMDcwNzU2LCJpYXQiOjE1NzMwNjk4NjYsImlzcyI6Ik9yaXNlYyJ9.UgUbLpM0Zs0KYT4XRy20Tkfc9SLgT-8EhhZziahper8",
    "TokenCreatedOnUtc": "0001-01-01T00:00:00",
    "TokenExpiresInMinutes": 15,
    "Roles": [
        "OrisecAdmin",
        "InstallerAdmin"
    ]
}
```

The POST request is as follows...

```
instancePost.post('/identity/account/login', {
    username: '***',
    password: '***'
})
    .then(function (response) {
        localStorage.setToken('access_token', JSON.stringify(response.data));
        localStorage.setToken('refresh_token', JSON.stringify(response.data));
        console.log(response);
    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

}

My local storage service is as follows...

```
// LocalStorageService.js
const LocalStorageService = (function () {
    var _service;
    function _getService() {
        if (!_service) {
            _service = this;
            return _service
        }
        return _service
    }
    function _setToken(tokenObj) {
        localStorage.setItem('access_token', tokenObj.access_token);
        localStorage.setItem('refresh_token', tokenObj.refresh_token)
    }
    function _getAccessToken() {
        return localStorage.getItem('access_token');
    }
    function _getRefreshToken() {
        return localStorage.getItem('refresh_token');
    }
    function _clearToken() {
        localStorage.removeItem('access_token');
        localStorage.removeItem('refresh_token');
    }
    return {
        getService: _getService,
        setToken: _setToken,
        getAccessToken: _getAccessToken,
        getRefreshToken: _getRefreshToken,
        clearToken: _clearToken
    }
})();
export default LocalStorageService;
```

I have tested the POST request in Postman and it works ok.
My question is how do I store the Token value in local storage.  Im currently doing this which stores the name but not the actual token.

```
 localStorage.setToken('access_token', JSON.stringify(response.data));
            localStorage.setToken('refresh_token', JSON.stringify(response.data));
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that your `localstorage` functionality is for `access_token` and `refresh_token`, but only a JWT token is provided. Additionally, it looks like you are using `setToken` instead of `setItem` as described [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem)

change

```
 localStorage.setToken('access_token', JSON.stringify(response.data));
```

to

```
localStorage.setItem('access_token', response.data.Token);
```

Since Token is a string type, you can access it like so:

```
localStorage.getItem('access_token', response.data.Token);
```